# Selecting from multiple tables in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

please help.I have a test booking table that looks like this

```
Schema::create('test_bookings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('RequestID');
        $table->string('bookingDate');
        $table->string('timeSlot');
        $table->unsignedInteger('nurse_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and a tests table that looks like this

```
Schema::create('tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('RequestID');
        $table->unsignedInteger('patientID');
        $table->string('barcode');
        $table->string('temperature');
        $table->string('pressure');
        $table->string('oxygen');
        $table->unsignedInteger('nurseID');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I want to show the RequestID,bookingDate,timeSlot, name and surname of the nurse only if the test_bookings RequestID is in tests table. This is my nurse table

```
Schema::create('nurses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('nurseID');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('surname');
        $table->string('idNumber');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->unsignedInteger('suburb_id');
        $table->timestamps();


        $table->index('suburb_id');
    });
```

This is the code that i tried

```
$tests =  DB::table('tests')
                ->select('RequestID','bookingDate','timeSlot','name','surname')
                ->join('nurses','nurses.nurseID','test_bookings.nurse_id')
                ->join('test_bookings','test_bookings.RequestID','=','tests.RequestID')
                ->get();
```

Comment: What is the problem you ran into with that code?

Comment: My table is not showing the data. If I select from test_bookings and join the nurses table, data is shown but when I join the tests table nothing is showing. I therefore tried as above code and still nothing is showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when I join the tests table nothing is showing

that because you are using [join](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#inner-join-clause)  clause that generate innerJoin statement, and to see the results you should use [leftJoin](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#left-join-right-join-clause)

```
$tests =  DB::table('tests')
                ->select('RequestID','bookingDate','timeSlot','name','surname')
                ->leftJoin('nurses','nurses.nurseID','=','test_bookings.nurse_id')
                ->leftJoin('test_bookings','test_bookings.RequestID','=','tests.RequestID')
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you're not using ORM here, a simple one-to-one relationship can do the job perfectly. Here is an example:

```
class TestBooking extends Model {
 # Other code...
 public function nurse(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Nurse::class);
  }
}
```

```
class Test extends Model {
 # Other code...
 public function testBooking(){
    return $this->belongsTo(TestBooking::class, 'RequestID','RequestID');
  }
}
```

Now you can get all data like this:

```
 $tests = Test::with("testBooking","testBooking.nurse")->get();
 // and get data inside loop like this:
 $test->RequestID // to get request ID
 $test->testBooking->bookingDate // to get booking date
 $test->testBooking->timeSlot // to get timeSlot
 $test->testBooking->nurse->name // to get nurse name
 $test->testBooking->nurse->surname // to get nurse surename
```

To know more about relationships [read documention](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships).